# How to stop my background colour extending past my text (CSS)

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend

I am struggling to prevent my background colour from extending past the text within it. I would ideally like the spacing on the right to match the spacing on the left but, as shown in this screenshot below, the right side will not shorten to match the left:

[image]

The code I am using for this is:

```
 <td>{user.workforce_roles.filter((wf_role) => wf_role.role.visible).map((wf_role) => {
    return <span key={wf_role.id} className="d-block">{wf_role.role.friendly_name}</span>;
  })}</td>
```

and styling:

```
.d-block {
  background-color: map-get($theme-colors, 'gapped');
  border-radius: px-to-rem(4px);
  margin-bottom: px-to-rem(6px);
  margin-right: px-to-rem(6px);
  padding: px-to-rem(2px) px-to-rem(8px);
  padding-right: px-to-rem(8px);
  position: relative;
}
```

It seems as though the width of the background is matching the longest text result but I'm not sure how to make it specific to each text case. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `display: inline-block` If that doesn't work we'd need a snippet that reproduces the problem. Is this the same `d-block` that you get from bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because your `span` elements are [`display: block`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) elements. Switch it to `display: inline-block`.

`display: block` example:

```css
span {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span>Text Text</span>
<span>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</span>
```

`display: inline-block` example:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span>Text Text</span><br>
<span>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</span>
```